# Daemonizing a shell script that runs rebar hangs

Tags: erlang, daemon, rebar

I am trying to run rebar from within a daemonized UNIX process.

This is an example of the line of code I am trying to run in a daemonized shell script:

```
~/rebar/rebar create template=mytemp nodeid=foo appid=foo
```

Why would this process be hanging and how do I work around this if possible?

To provide some context into why i am doing this:

I desire to be able to do this, or have a work around, because I need to create an erlang application and generate a release as part of a much larger project build. The build is assembled on demand by requesting a daemon process to start a build.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this problem. My advice is to use run `rebar` in the daemon under `strace` and capture the output in a file, as that might help narrow down where the hang occurs.

Comment: I'll need to take a look on how to diagnose the strace output myself, but  when I run rebar under a deamon the strace ends with:
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

When run outside of the daemon it ends with:
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL <unfinished ... exit status 0>

Comment: From what I am reading here, I'm guessing that this means that this process is hung waiting for stdin?

Comment: Seems unlikely. If the parent environment is properly daemonized, rebar's stdin would be attached to /dev/null and so any reads would immediately return EOF. Also, I ran rebar from my command line with stdin redirected from /dev/null and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang releases use run_erl (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html) for running release and you can use run_erl for start single application.

Example:

```
./rebar create-app appid=test
==> test (create-app)
Writing src/test.app.src
Writing src/test_app.erl
Writing src/test_sup.erl

run_erl -daemon /tmp/ /tmp/ "exec erl -pa ebin -s test_app"
```

And you have logs in /tmp dir and pipes.

Comment: The question isn't about running releases generated by `rebar`, but rather about `rebar` itself hanging when executed within a daemon process.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am trying to run rebar from within a daemon process. I will rephrase my original post to make that unambigous. Thanks